# Can't email internally using Postfix

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I've just setup a mail server on a CentOS dedicated server. I can successfully send email and receive email, using TLS and everything, so that part is perfect.

The problem, however, is that I can't send emails to people from the same server using an email from the same server.

So, me@example.com can't send emails to you@example.com, but me@gmail.com can send emails to both me@example.com and you@example.com.

I can't send emails from me@hosted-website1.com to me@hosted-website2.com.

A snippet from my maillog:

```
Dec 22 07:58:34 king postfix/smtpd[13022]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qy0-f172.google.com[209.85.216.172]: 550 5.1.1 <steve@domain.ca>:
Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table; from=<jason@domain.ca> to=<steve@domain.ca> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qy0-f172.google.com>
```

Not too sure what information to give, so let me if you need more info. As I said, I can email steve@domain.ca properly using my jason@gmail.com.

Note: All email addresses are fictional.

EDIT: I should specify that I use Virtualmin. I have the virtual_alias_maps set in my main.cf to `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`. In the virtual file, I got plenty of entries generated by Virtualmin such as:

```
jason@valdron.ca        jason.valdron
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put your local domain in virtual_alias_domains.

Don't do this.

Comment: Not really a clear answer..."You have to do X, don't do X."

Comment: Check out my edit. Also, @BartSilverstrim, it's a proper answer, he said that I did something, but don't do it. However, the phrasing used is kinda weird :)

Comment: AH that's what got me. I read a "to" in it when there wasn't, like you have to do X. Now I see. Derp on me.

Comment: Was kinda that, my local domain was in my maps, thanks!

Comment: As documented, virtual_alias_domains defaults to $virtual_alias_maps, and any bare domain in virtual_alias_maps is automatically a virtual_alias_domain. This is legacy behaviour.